# Distorted bibliography after input file

Tags: bibliographies, input

I'm writing my dissertation, and each chapter is one of my papers. So, instead of having a single reference section, I have each reference section for each chapter. Moreover, as there are multiple chapters, I use the

```
\input{filename}
```

for each chapter. However, the problem is that the references cited in each chapter got a different form. For example, instead of Smith et al. (2009), I have ith et al. (2009) s (a). I should say that I use

```
\begin{thebibliography}
...
\end{thebibliography}
```

in each chapter.

Any help or idea would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> I should say that I use
>
> \begin{thebibliography}
>      ...
>      \end{thebibliography}
>
> in each chapter.

and basically that's your problem. The Latex infrastructure (primarily the temporary files created) assumes one bibliography per document. What you are looking for is something like bibunits, see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bibunits?lang=de